# ODOO -12 NOTIFICATION SETUP

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10, odoo-11, odoo-12

I am a starter in odoo. Can anyone help me to find a solution for the problem mentioned below?

in CRM Module , i want a mail when manger should be notified of any changes made to the Records and manager should be notified 90 days prior to expiry of subscription and automatically

Can anyone help me to achieve this goal. Thanks in advance.

Comment: install mail module and there will be a model called `mail.message`, this can send the notification to specific users or groups.

Comment: automation in odoo is build in `ir.cron`. Search this key word in odoo source will find many applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guna Str

1) manager should be notified of any changes made to the Records
- Define an `automated action` to `send` the `email` if the value of the `Stage` field changes on an `update` of the record.

2) manager should be notified 90 days prior to the expiry of subscription
- You can do with the `track_visibility` with customizing the logic based on the explain way(days calculating) or for mail you also do with the `automated action`(with python way).

Comment: thanks i have done the first one , but second one can u share some links or code that would help me

Comment: In my way, I add a computational field (type boolean) to judge whether the day is expired or not. then add decoration-danger="the_field == True" as tree attribution.

Comment: Search `decoration-` then you will find bunches of example in odoo source.

Comment: in which approach you're asking with the track_visibility or mail send with action?